# Opening Pycharm via terminal

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pycharm, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.
Everytime I open pycharm community edition from terminal:

```
$ pycharm-community
```

I get the following message:

> uim_helper_get_pathname() failed

The program then works fine. Today it's the first time I get this error though.
Any idea why it happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention of this error in the PyCharm issue tracker [1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY?q=uim_helper_get_pathname). You might want to create a new issue there if you want to.

What might not directly answer your question, but might help you is the following. On Ubuntu you can install pycharm via snap. This handles the installation and updating of pycharm for you. Might also resolve this error. You can install pycharm via:

`sudo snap install pycharm-community`

More information: https://snapcraft.io/pycharm-community

Comment: I did installed it via snap